# Managing the pressButton with panels

Tags: java, swing

Roles I should follow:

1)when a panel is clicked, it's color is changed. But if we reclick a second time the same panel, the color don't change because it's still clicked
boolean isPressed = true or false.

2) when panel1 is clicked(keep pressed) and the mouse is moved to panel2(otherwise, panel2 is highlighted) and after that we release the mouse click. Panel1 and panel2 take the same color.
boolean isHighlighted = true or false.

3)In the second role panel2 was highlighted, so if we click on it or we try to hover on it from the panel3, the color don't change.

I have a megacode with models and Views, So their is a lot of things to show. What I'm not enable to understand is how to manage this with Listener. Puting listener in each panel was not handy. So some how recommand me to put my listener in the mainPanel and manage from it ???.[image]

**EDIT**

This is my code:

```
package mouseeventdemo;

/*
* MouseEventDemo.java
*/

import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseListener;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;

import javax.swing.*;

public class MouseEventDemo extends JPanel implements MouseListener {
    BlankArea blankArea1;
    BlankArea blankArea2;
    JTextArea textArea;
    BlankArea  label; 
    static final String NEWLINE = System.getProperty("line.separator");

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        /* Use an appropriate Look and Feel */
        try {
            //UIManager.setLookAndFeel("com.sun.java.swing.plaf.windows.WindowsLookAndFeel");
            //UIManager.setLookAndFeel("com.sun.java.swing.plaf.gtk.GTKLookAndFeel");
            UIManager.setLookAndFeel("javax.swing.plaf.metal.MetalLookAndFeel");
        } catch (UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
        /* Turn off metal's use of bold fonts */
        UIManager.put("swing.boldMetal", Boolean.FALSE);
        //Schedule a job for the event dispatch thread:
        //creating and showing this application's GUI.
        javax.swing.SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                createAndShowGUI();
            }
        });
    }

    /**
     * Create the GUI and show it.  For thread safety,
     * this method should be invoked from the
     * event dispatch thread.
     */
    private static void createAndShowGUI() {
        //Create and set up the window.
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("MouseEventDemo");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        //Create and set up the content pane.
        JComponent newContentPane = new MouseEventDemo();
        newContentPane.setOpaque(true); //content panes must be opaque
        frame.setContentPane(newContentPane);

        //Display the window.
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public MouseEventDemo() {

        super(new GridLayout(0,1));
        blankArea1 = new BlankArea();
        blankArea1.setName("YELLOW");
        add(blankArea1);
        blankArea2 = new BlankArea();
        blankArea2.setName("RED");
        add(blankArea2);
        textArea = new JTextArea();
        textArea.setEditable(false);
        JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(textArea);
        scrollPane.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(
                JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);
        scrollPane.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(200, 75));
        add(scrollPane);
        // add(test,BorderLayout.CENTER);
        //Register for mouse events on blankArea and the panel.
        blankArea1.addMouseListener(this);
        blankArea2.addMouseListener(this);
        //addMouseListener(this);

        /*addMouseMotionListener(new MouseAdapter() {
            public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent e) {
                eventOutput("Mouse moved main panel", e);
            }

            public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e) {
                eventOutput("Mouse dragged main panel ", e);
            }
        });*/

        setPreferredSize(new Dimension(450, 450));
        setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(20,20,20,20));
    }

    void eventOutput(String eventDescription, MouseEvent e) {
        textArea.append(eventDescription + " detected on "
                + e.getComponent().getName()
                + "." + NEWLINE);
        textArea.setCaretPosition(textArea.getDocument().getLength());
    }

    public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
       label = (BlankArea ) e.getSource();
       eventOutput("Mouse pressed (# of clicks: "+ e.getClickCount() + ")", e);
    }

    public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {
        label = (BlankArea ) e.getSource();
        eventOutput("Mouse released (# of clicks: " + e.getClickCount() + ")", e);
    }

    public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {
        label = (BlankArea ) e.getSource();
        eventOutput("Mouse entered", e);
    }

    public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {
        label = (BlankArea ) e.getSource();
        eventOutput("Mouse exited", e);
    }

    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
        eventOutput("Mouse clicked (# of clicks: "+ e.getClickCount() + ")", e);
    }
}


    class BlankArea extends JLabel {
      Dimension minSize = new Dimension(100, 50);
      public boolean isPressed;
      public boolean isHilighted;

    public BlankArea(Color color) {
        setBackground(color);
        setOpaque(true);
        setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.black));
    }

    public BlankArea() {
        isPressed = false;
        isHilighted = false;
        setOpaque(true);
        setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.black));
    }

    public Dimension getMinimumSize() {
        return minSize;
    }

    public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
        return minSize;
    }
```

}

Comment: Maintain the responsibility where it belongs, for example `mousePressed` events should be managed by the individual components, as they need to be able to make decisions about how to deal with it based on there current state.  `mouseDragged` events may need to be managed by the parent container (attached to each child panel), as the interaction from to the other is greater then the single child itself.  The parent can make decisions about where the first panel was dropped and tell the child when it occurs

Comment: Mouse dragging need (x,y) positions. I have no experience with this sorry.

Comment: MouseEvent will return the x/y coordinates of the event within the context of the component which generated it

Comment: Have a look at [How to write a MouseListener](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/mouselistener.html) and [How to write a MouseMotionListener](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/mousewheellistener.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For each button in the panel add this : `buttonName.addActionListener(this);`. Then in your actionPerformed method, do all your calculations and restrictions.

Comment: This is what I have done, but problem still happed. Ex: panel3 does not knows if panel2 is highlighted. and so one.

Comment: Then the problem would be in your actionPerformed method. Can you post a piece of your code so the problem you are getting can be analysed better.